# Struggling to understand what does this mean? [diff fileA fileB | grep ‘^<’]

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I know that the meta-character ^ means to match the empty string at the beginning. However, what does the '<' mean in grep?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: It means exactly `<`

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that's just the character being searched for?

`diff` shows the differences between two files, with `<<<<<` preceding lines only in the first file. piping it to `grep` pulls out all lines matching that regex: namely "lines that start with the '<' character". I don't think this is a very useful command, as you'd simply get a bunch of lines like so:

```
<<<<<
<<<<<
<<<<<
(etc...)
```

Maybe the purpose of the line is to detect if there are *any* differences between the files? (Otherwise, `grep` will find nothing)